# Is there a way to bypass the required attribute "term" in the iTunes search API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, itunes, itunes-search-api

I'm using the iTunes search API (more specifically [this gem](https://github.com/rlivsey/itunes-search-api) for rails) for an app where the most important part of the query is the genre. I have a checklist where the user can select a certain genre and the matching genreId will be searched for in the query. However, I cannot figure out what to put in the term field that will apply to all results returned, and I cannot omit that attribute because it is required. If I put in the name of the genre, like "Technology", then only podcasts with the word "technology" in the title or artist name are returned, which is not ideal.

```
ITunesSearchAPI.search(:term=> "????", :genreId=> @genre_id , :country => "US", :entity=> "podcast", :media => "podcast", :limit => 15)
```

I've tried "+" since "URL encoding replaces spaces with the plus (+) character"  according to the [iTunes search API documentation](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html). I've also tried "podcast", which produces the same issue as above. Is there any way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can't bypass `term` because it's required parameter.

To make url-encoded string you need to use `URI::encode('string')` method.

Like this:

```
require 'open-uri'
ITunesSearchAPI.search(:term=> URI::encode('Super mega podcast'), :genreId=> @genre_id , :country => "US", :entity=> "podcast", :media => "podcast", :limit => 15)
```